# Tomcat-Maven 401 Error: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager

Tags: tomcat, maven, spring-mvc, m2eclipse

Went through most of the errors shown in StackOverFlow and still couldn't solve it. I'm trying to deploy a SpringMVC application. But, I just can't get it to work.

Maven Deploy Error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:redeploy (default-cli) on project productmgmt: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2Fproductmgmt&war=&update=true -> [Help 1]
```

Pom.xml:

```
<build>
        <finalName>productmgmt</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                    <path>/productmgmt</path>
                    <username>admin</username>
                    <password>password</password>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Tomcat-Users.xml

```
<role rolename="admin"/>
  <role rolename="manager"/>
  <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="admin,manager"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

More Information:

```
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

This worked for me

```
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<role rolename="admin-script"/>
<user password="password" roles="manager-script,admin-script" username="admin"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Comment: admin-script thingy did it for me. Had no idea about this role. Thanks, lifesaver !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your maven configuration has the username and password set as `admin/password`. In the Tomcat configuration they are set as `admin/admin`.

Switch your `pom.xml` to have `<password>admin</password>`.

Also, the roles need changing for the admin user as per the [Tomcat docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html). You'll want the **manager-gui** role to access the HTML manager and the **manager-script** role to access the text interface.

Comment: Can you access the manager app from your browser using those credentials?

Comment: I think issue here is that the role names aren't quite right. The Tomcat 7.0 docs state that to access the text-based manager API, the user needs to have the manager-script role.

Comment: Thanks. The **manager-gui** vs **manager-script** was the issue for me since I wanted to deploy to `http://server:8080/manager/text`