# How to fix "Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 "

Tags: eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee, tomcat

i am using maven, eclipse and tomcat7. i am trying to deploy my web application in tomcat with `clean tomcat:deploy` command , but every time i get this error :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) on project azraspina: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://localhost:8080/manager/html/deploy?path=%2Fazraspina&war= -> [Help 1]
```

this is the plugin part of my pom.xml :

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <username>admin</username>
            <password>admin</password>
            <server>raspinaserver</server>
            <path>/azraspina</path>
            <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/html</url>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

</plugins>
```

and this is part of my tomcat-users.xml :

```
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui" />
  <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
  <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
  <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
```

so far i have tried almost everything on the web! i have added the credential part of pom.xml to setting.xml of maven but it didn't solve the problem.i also tried to use "tomcat7-maven-plugin" but still no luck. i even tried hitting my head over the cement wall ahap(as hard as possible) but i am still alive so no luck there either.
so, would you please help me to solve this problem?
thank you

Comment: what does the Tomcat's log say? Or the `manager` app's log, if such exists?

Comment: @yair No server username specified - using default

Comment: and that's the only line of log printed as result of the `deploy` goal? Is it displayed as an error? If answers are true for both questions then please paste both `server.xml` and tomcat-users.xml` files to your question.

Comment: You may have problem with the user **roles**. Read this answer: [Tomcat-Maven 401 Error: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12753598/814702)

Answer (score 2):

If you are deploying to Tomcat 7, you might consider using the [Tomcat 7 Maven plugin from Apache](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/) instead of the Codehaus version.

Typically, credentials do not go into the plugin configuration in the POM, as the POM ends up in an artifact repository and is usually shared with other developers.  Credentials go in the settings.xml `<servers>` element, then you configure the plugin to reference that server.  This is what the [Tomcat 7 plugin usage docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/tomcat7-maven-plugin/usage.html) and the [Codehaus tomcat plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/usage.html) describe.

So, your settings.xml:

```
....
<servers>
  <server>
      <id>raspinaserver</id>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>admin</password>
  </server>
</servers>
...
```

And the plugin config:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <server>raspinaserver</server>
      <path>/azraspina</path>
      <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/html</url>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: thanks for reply. i tried this but didnt solve the problem. i think i move on to jetty

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the credentials should better be configured in the *settings.xml* and NOT in the POM.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem could be in the **manager URL**. Try this on your **pom.xml** :

```
<url>http://localhost:8080/manager/html</url>
```

instead of :

```
<url>http://localhost:8080/manager</url>
```

I couldn't find documentation about those URLs (surely exists), but anyway it works for me to deploy to **apache-tomcat-6.0.39** using **tomcat-maven-plugin v1.1**

That's a second possible problem in your pom.xml : you haven't specified **which version of the plugin to use**. It can work ... but it's error prone. Maven even warns about these things. I use this on my pom.xml :

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <url>http://localhost:8080/manager</url>
    <server>MyTomcat</server>
    <path>/agalindo-webui</path>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

There I have specified the server like [user944849](https://stackoverflow.com/users/944849/user944849) sugests on my settings.xml (**~/.m2/settings.xml**), like this:

```
<settings>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>MyTomcat</id>
      <username>myusername</username>
      <password>mypassword</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
  <!-- .. -->
</settings>
```

Hope it helps,

/ Angel