# Cannot invoke Tomcat manager w/Jenkins

Tags: maven, tomcat, jenkins

I'm managing the builds for a web service with Jenkins, and I've run into a problem with Tomcat.  I'm getting the following error and stack trace:

```
mavenExecutionResult exceptions not empty
message : Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:redeploy(default-cli) on project rnr: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager
cause : Cannot invoke Tomcat manager
Stack trace : 
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:redeploy (default-cli) on project rnr: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager
```

Here's my pom configuration for the Tomcat maven plugin:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                <server>TomcatServer</server>
                <path>/</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

EDIT: I'm using Tomcat 7.0.42.

I'm not sure exactly what the problem is or if I've provided enough information, so let me know if more is needed.  This is the first time I've run into this problem, and to my knowledge nothing in the pom or jenkins setup has changed, so I don't know where this error is coming from.

Thank you!!

Comment: which version of tomcat you are using?

Comment: May be this can help ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12753578/tomcat-maven-401-error-cannot-invoke-tomcat-manager